# .htaccess redirect url to different location based on get paramteres

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect url to different location based on get parameters , it seems only first rules works form this while rest of them is ignored.

```
http://example.com/def?attachment_id=365    http://example.com/abcdef
http://example.com/def?attachment_id=360   http://example.com/hujkl
```

**Below is code i was using :**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^attachment_id=365$
RewriteRule ^def/$ http://example.com/abcdef [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^attachment_id=360$
RewriteRule ^def/$ http://example.com/hujkl [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} attachment_id=365
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} page_id=8
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/def? [L,R=301]
```